# Not able to successfully authenticate user using Firebase PhoneAuth in iOS App developed using Flutter

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase PhoneAuth to authenticate users. I have done all the integrations as per instructions from reliable sources on the net.

The error that I'm facing is that, I'm not receiving call back for the code sent handler in verifyPhoneNumber method of Firebase Auth.

Here is methods used, once the user enters the phone number, the signInWithPhone() is called which in turn calls the verifyPhoneNumber().

```
Future<AuthUser> signInWithPhone(String phone) async {

 await _firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
 phoneNumber: phone,
 timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
 verificationCompleted: _phoneVerificationCompleted,
 verificationFailed: _phoneVerificationFailed,
 codeSent: _phoneCodeSent,
 codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: _phoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
 print("Phone Authentication Ended");
 return null;
}

_phoneCodeSent(String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
 phoneVerificationId = verificationId;
}
```

Here the _phoneCodeSent() should get called when the otp has been sent. The verificationId received in this method is required for authentication purpose. Since the function doesn't get invoked I'm not receiving the verificationId but the otp is getting generated.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen I have added more details to the question. Now is it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have followed these docs of firebase integration with flutter,
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/ios
And iOS Specific setup as per this https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone#setup along with 4 specific handlers.

Comment: I have followed all the integration docs and I'm receiving the OTP as well. But the issue I'm facing is that the code sent handler is not getting called after the OTP is sent. You can view my question as I have provided the code. The auth flow is working in android but facing this issue in iOS.